# Posterior probabilities with decision trees or decision forests

Tags: bayesian, cart, posterior, boosting, calibration

Is there a way to get posterior probabilities $P(C | \vec{x})$ (probability that a data item $\vec{x}$ belong to one of the given classes) in a multiclass classification problem using decision trees or forests?

I found some hints about using calibration methods (e.g. Platt's method or Isotonic Regression) in combination with boosted or bagged trees. However, as I'm not experienced in this field I can't find a good explanation how this works. It would be very helpful if one of you could explain me the general idea how to get posterior probabilities with decision trees or a good link or paper where these things are explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in section 2.2.4 of the paper [Decision Forests for Classification, Regression, Density Estimation, Manifold Learning and Semi-Supervised Learning](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=155552).

> In the case of classification each leaf may store the empirical distribution over the classes associated to the subset of training data that has reached that leaf.

During testing, each tree leaf yields a distribution over classes and the forest output is the average of these leaf distributions.

Answer (score 1):

You can decompose  a forest into trees. Each tree with depth 'n' separate data in 2^n split maximum. So everytime you do a prediction, the output of each tree represent the belonging to one class, then a majority vote is done (for classification), you can estimate the posterior  of each tree with the specific data who likely belong to the split your vector fall in .
If you want the posterior of your forest you can consider the values of all tree estimator (only with bagging, boosting structure do not allow it by nature).